# Does North Korea propaganda falsely claim 2014 World Cup participation?

Tags: sport, media, north-korea, football

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJoRZOK18Fg) is being spread on Facebook. It purports to be a North Korean television segment that fraudulently tells the North Koreans that they are participating in the 2014 World Cup in Brazil, and that North Korea have defeated USA, China and Japan.

Everyone is spreading this as a genuine piece of North Korean propaganda. This "Korean News Backup" is a 2 month old channel, with lots of North Korean videos from other sources and some of original content too. None of the other North Korean media YouTube videos I found have this reporter in the cast.

Is this legitimate North Korean propaganda? A segment from a South Korean comedy show spoofing the North Koreans? Or a well-produced Internet hoax?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is very likely to be a fake.

According to [NKnews](http://www.nknews.org/2014/06/north-korea-televises-brazil-2014-world-cup-matches/), The World Cup games are aired in North Korea by KCTV (although with delay and removed commentary), so it appears that there is no sense in faking news while the general population is aware of the developments at the World Cup, at least to some extent. Also, since the North Korea qualification games were aired, they [do know that their team didn't qualify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPyHoDcwbzE).